# Azure AD authentication with Airflow

Tags: azure, oauth, airflow

*TLDR: Where can I find the logs of Flask App Builder to see what's going wrong?*

I'm trying to configure Azure AD Oauth2 to let users sign in before using Airflow. I have the following configuration in my webserver_config:

```
tenant_id = "id"
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        "name": "azure",
        "icon": "fa-windows",
        "token_key": "access_token",
        "remote_app": {
            "client_id": "id",
            "client_secret": "secret",
            "base_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2",
            "scope": "User.Read",
            "request_token_url": None,
            "access_token_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/token",
            "authorize_url": f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        },
    },
]
```

In airflow.cfg, I set `rbac = True` and `[webserver] authenticate = True`. When I start the web server, I get to login but then I'm redirected to an Airflow debug page that gives me a 500 response. Where can I find the logs of Flask App Builder to see what's going wrong?

Comment: For those visiting this in the future, I've tried to capture up-to-date working instructions here: https://gist.github.com/wallyhall/915fedb4dfc766b61f442a32c95e1c29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable the logs for Flask App Builder by setting this Config param - AIRFLOW__LOGGING__FAB_LOGGING_LEVEL , to appropriate log level.

Refer the docs here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#fab-logging-level